# Quarkus REST Jackson object mapper configuration does not seem to work

Tags: quarkus

I have added the jackson extension to my quarkus gradle project (0.23.2), however this configuration does not seem to be applied when running my application and calling my rest endpoint:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class ObjectMapperConfiguration {

    @Singleton
    @Produces
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY);

        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

The json serialized still includes null entries and empty arrays. This is following the example on the quarkus guides.

on start-up, I can see that the jackson extension is present:

```
2019-10-08 07:04:00,613 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Installed features: [cdi, hibernate-validator, resteasy, resteasy-jackson, smallrye-openapi, swagger-ui]
```

Have I missed something?

example of the jackson serialized output returned from a curl http request:

```
"code":"invalid.request", "message": null, "attributes": null, "errors": [{"code":"data", "message":"must not be blank","attributes":null,"errors":null}]}
```

as you can see, message and attributes are being output despite being configured not to.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: About the desired configuration, you only need : `objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY);` because it already includes `JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL`

Answer (score 15):

there is an easy way to do that, take a look at https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-json.

Your code should be some like that:

```
@Singleton
public class RegisterCustomModuleCustomizer implements ObjectMapperCustomizer {
    @Override
    public void customize(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure this is supported right now. But the good news is that we have a brand new JSON customization feature coming in 0.24.0 (which should be released tomorrow).

You can find more information about it here: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/main/docs/src/main/asciidoc/rest-json.adoc#jackson .

It will allow you to customize the `ObjectMapper` easily.

Comment: Ah that's good timing! Thanks will wait until tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: We had some issues releasing 0.24.0 due to a Sonatype outage but it's now there. And the doc has been pushed to the website: https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-json-guide#configuring-json-support .

Comment: Once you customize the `ObjectMapper`, is there a way you can later inject it and use it in other classes?

Comment: Looks like you can inject it using constructor injection. Initially, using field injection, I was getting a NPE.